# Getting proper date format with php

Tags: php, date, browser, format

I have a date field in html. From it I transmit date via POST in php to another file and different browsers transmit it in different formats. For example, chrome 2014-12-30, mozilla 30.12.2014. How I can easily change date format, when I assign this field to php variable?

Comment: Try [`DateTime`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/de/book.datetime.php).

Comment: Get browser name from SERVER details and convert to time as per browser condition.

Answer (score 0):

change with `date()` in php

```
$date = '30.12.2014';
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

or `datetime()`

```
$datetime = new DateTime($date);
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the DateTime class to create a date formatting the date is very easy.

```
$dateNow = new DateTime();
```

Then to format the date into the wanted format you use the format method

```
$dateNow->format('Y-m-d') // Google Chrome
$dateNow->format('d.m.Y') // Mozilla Firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

Use date with strtotime. The first argument in date() is the format you desire, the second is  the strtotime'd date you have pulled.

```
echo date('d m y', strtotime("date POST var here"));
```

Answer (score 0):

with the [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) function, you can get localized dates.

use it along with `setlocale()`

example from php.net:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "C");
echo strftime("%A");
setlocale(LC_TIME, "fi_FI");
echo strftime(" in Finnish is %A,");
setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR");
echo strftime(" in French %A and");
setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE");
echo strftime(" in German %A.\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    // Next get the name of the useragent yes seperately and for good reason
    if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
    {
        echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
        //your code
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent))
    {
       echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date));
       //your code
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent))
    {
       echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
       //your code
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent))
    {
       echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
       //your code
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
    {
       echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
       //your code
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent))
    {
       echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
       //your code
    }



?>
```